# pear include_path data folder is no longer valid

Tags: php, centos, pear

I have a vps with centOS LAMP stack, and multiple domains/ips. A long time ago I had someone more familiar with SSH install pear on the vps, and I believe he configured it for a specific user/domain, which no longer exists, and now pear is throwing errors.

The old user/domain which no longer exists is "ljsspin" but when I look at my php.ini, the include path is:

```
include_path = ".:/usr/share/pear/:/usr/share/php:/var/www/ljsspin/data/pear/:"
```

I can execute pear commands in ssh, but I'm assuming the fact that the last portion of that include path no longer exists is the reason for the error.

So my question is how do I install the necessary /data/pear files into a new directory? I've tried upgrading pear, and that, too, produced an error (unable to unpackage a structure file).

Thanks for any guidance.

Exact error message I receive:

```
Warning: include() [function.include]: open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/usr/share/pear/Mail.php) is not within the allowed path(s): (/var/www/steve/data:.) in /var/www/steve/data/www/newdomain.com/admin/dashboard/includes/pdf.php on line 3

Warning: include(/usr/share/pear/Mail.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: Operation not permitted in /var/www/steve/data/www/newdomain.com/admin/dashboard/includes/pdf.php on line 3

Warning: include() [function.include]: Failed opening 'Mail.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear/:/usr/share/php:/var/www/ljsspin/data/pear/:') in /var/www/steve/data/www/newdomain.com/admin/dashboard/includes/pdf.php on line 3
```

Comment: It always helps to post the exact error message (use clipboard to copy and paste) and explain how to trigger it (are you talking about running `pear` in console or about using PEAR packages from within PHP code?).

Comment: Just added the exact error. I did verify that /usr/share/pear/Mail.php was in the proper location, by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **open_basedir restriction in effect** error message means that you've set a value for the [open_basedir](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir) PHP directive so scripts are not allowed to read files from outside a given set of directories, which in your case are these:

- `/var/www/steve/data`
- `.`

Since PEAR packages are installed in some other directory:

- `/usr/share/pear/`

... PHP prevents scripts from reading them, as it's been instructed to do.

If you intend to allow access to `/usr/share/pear/`, you'll obviously have to broaden the restriction.

Comment: phpinfo has the following: open_basedir /var/www/steve/data:. no value

Comment: Local values override master values.

Comment: open_basedir was set to none, safe_mode turned off and the errors are gone. I replace the missing directory portion of the include path with the correct domain, so I guess there were no necessary files to be copied over? Thanks